# When using the French word "sans" in an English sentence, should I use italics?

Tags: writing-style, loanwords, italics, foreign-phrases

In the sentence, below, I am using the French word *sans* to mean *without*. Should sans be italicized? Or, should all of "sans human civilization" be italicized?

> Planet Earth sans human civilization is imagined, at least by Teasdale, to beautiful, harmonious, and ultimately superior to the human-centred world we live in now.

OR

> Planet Earth *sans* human civilization is imagined, at least by Teasdale, to beautiful, harmonious, and ultimately superior to the human-centred world we live in now.

Comment: Seems like you should only use italic for Italian.

Comment: @HotLicks Who on earth says that?

Comment: Using a well-understood foreign term to call up an accepted idea (e.g. as lawyers employ Latin), can be a succinct and expressive way of getting one's meaning across. Talking about the late 19th century a historian might, for example, refer to the nationalist *zeitgeist* of the age. It is the well-understood term that historians have assigned to *the spirit of the age*. But *zeitgeist* adds something else if one is discussing that period, since Germany represents the quintessence of 19th-century nationalism. But using just an odd preposition,*sans*, smacks of simply trying to be pretentious.

Comment: @WS2 Thanks for the advice. Pretentious is the last thing I want to be.

Comment: @WS2 I believe it was a pun on the shared etymology of _italic_ and _Italian_. French ought presumably to be written in Frankic. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I was thinking that "frantic" would be more suitable.  Or maybe "frenetic".

Comment: I'd write the sentence sans italics, but would add a disclaimer.  (pardon the French(excuse the French(forgive the French(overlook the German)))). Wow, English gets a lot of sorry French.

Comment: Much of the language we speak and write is composed of  terms--such as *zeitgeist* and *sans*--appropriated whole or embedded in our Anglicizations. The well-placed and well-timed foreign word or short phrase can add savor. What is soup sans salt?

Comment: @WS2 I'd hardly call "sans" an odd or pretentious preposition. As Sven's answer says, it's been incorporated into English for centuries.

Comment: I very seldom (if ever) hear it used in Britain, except in a quoted French expression - in italics. Perhaps America acquired it with the Louisiana purchase!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As a matter of style, many U.S. publishers follow the general rules given by the *Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003) at 7.51, 7.53, and 7.54 under the heading "FOREIGN WORDS":

> **7.51** *Italics.* Italics are used for isolated words and phrases in a foreign language if they are likely to be unfamiliar to readers. [Examples omitted.]
>
> ...
>
> **7.53** *Proper nouns.* Foreign proper nouns are not italicized in an English context. [Examples omitted.]
>
> **7.54** *Familiar foreign words.* Foreign words and phrases familiar to most readers and listed in Webster are not italicized if used in an English context; they should be spelled as in Webster. ...

Guideline 7.54 is the relevant one for your question about *sans*—and any other arguably foreign word you might be thinking of using. If the word is in the English dictionary that you normally use (and it doesn't have to be a Merriam-Webster product, Chicago's wording notwithstanding), you may treat it as an adopted English word and thus as not requiring italics to indicate its foreignness. This certainly is the case with *sans*, which has been in use in English since the fourteenth century (according to MW) and appears in such memorable quotations as Jaques's speech about the seven ages of man, in Shakespeare's *As You Like It*:

> Last scene of all,/That ends this strange eventful history,/Is second childishness and mere oblivion,/Sans teeth, sans eyes, sans taste, sans everything.

So if you're inclined to follow Chicago's lead on this question, have a dictionary handy when you prepare to use what may or may not be viewed as a non-English word.

Comment: If it were possible, I would upvote this answer +10 because it absolutely correct. As @WS2 noted, lawyers regularly use words that originated in foreign languages. As a former lawyer who did a significant amount of legal writing and especially editing, the CMS guidance is fantastic. Italics are a signal to the reader that the word deserves special attention. If the foreign word is likely unfamiliar, then the signal is useful. If the loan word has been fully assimilated then the signal is a distraction or potentially confusing. **No italics for sans.** Great answer, Sven.

Comment: Well done for digging out the Shakespeare. But I have to say I have never, in my lifetime, heard *sans* used in Britain as though it were an English word. Some uninspiring people name their houses or boats *Sans souci*, but that is entirely French.

Comment: Further to that I have looked in the OED and you may be interested in what it says in the matter of ***sans***.
*Without. Now arch. (chiefly with reminiscence of Shakespeare), joc., and Heraldry.
Before the time of Shakespeare used almost exclusively with ns. adopted from Old French, in collocations already formed in that language, as sans delay, sans doubt, sans fable, sans pity, sans return. Even in some of our earliest examples, however, a native English synonym has been substituted for the Romanic n. in the phrase, as in sans biding = sans delay.*


α.

Comment: @WS2: In publishing (especially design), one standard use of _sans_ is in the term "sans serif type." _Sans_ comes up in the context of things like crossword-puzzle clues, too. I think it's fairly common in various situations in U.S. English.

Comment: @SvenYargs One thing puzzles me.If *sans* was widely used in English at the time of Shakespeare one would expect to find some instances of it in the KJV bible (pub 1611). but having just done a search of the entire Bible the only instance of the letters SANS are in one proper name Sansannah in the Book of Joshua.

Comment: @WS2: Your point is valid and interesting. Shakespeare uses it elsewhere—in _King John_ ("FAULKENBRIDGE: Come, come; _sans compliment_, what news abroad? HUBERT: Why, here walk I in the black brow of night to find you out.") and in _Troylus and Cressida_ ("ULYSSES: ... And therefore is the glorious Planet Sol/In noble eminence, enthroned and sphear'd/Amid'st the other, whose med'cinable eye/Corrects the ill Aspects of Planets euill,/And postes like the Command'ment of a King,/Sans checke, to good and bad.")—but a Google Books search doesn't find it in his contemporaries' writing.

Comment: @WS2 you might try googling for "sans underwear" :-). "Sans" does seem to be actively used in Modern English whatever the OED might think.

Comment: @WS2 - thank you for your research, perhaps that should be added to SvenYargs's answer - in particular that it hints that sans is archaic in British English, but current in American English.

Comment: @Qsigma I've dealt with Americans all my working life, and I've never heard one say *sans* meaning *without*.

Comment: +1 Great answer– loved the Shakespeare reference. Very helpful.

Comment: @WS2 Interesting. Yet so many comments above contradict that. Perhaps it is a recent affectation of geek sub-culture. Otherwise I agree with you that it is an archaic loanword. For that reason I would recommend (optional) italics.

Comment: @WS2, what does OED say about the pronunciation?

Comment: @Chris I'm not familiar with the phonetic alphabet but this is what it says: Pronunciation:
   /sanz/  /sɒ̃/

Comment: @WS2 I almost always have to refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_English but your OED appears to say it can be pronounced as a  naive English reading, or as it would be in French.

Comment: @Chris H: In the case of the typographical term "sans serif," which I mentioned in a comment above, the normal U.S. pronunciation of _sans_ is "san" as in "San Francisco" or "San Simeon"; but in font names such as "Comic Sans," the pronunciation is (as WS2 notes) "sanz."

Comment: @SvenYargs, that's interesting and makes [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_reward_check](San Seriffe) seem more logical.  Of course you don't always hear two clear *s*s anyway in this sort of construction. Either way the vowel is different to what I'm used to in the UK.  I wonder what other variants of English do.

Comment: @ChrisH By the way it's not MY OED! It is the OED of the English language, across many different corpuses. It is as much an authority on the American variety as on any other. The advantage we have is that, because we still have library services on the public purse (only just, they are under threat) most local authorities hold a subscription, so we can access it on-line simply with our local tax reference number.

Comment: @WS2 I did assume it was your subscription. I didn't know it was possible to use a library subscription online - I'll have to see if something similar is possible round here.

Comment: @ChrisH Are you in the UK? Most local authority libraries have a subscription to both the OED and the Oxford Dictionary of National Biography - and other things besides. All you need to do is use your library card to log in. In our case it is the same card which also provides things like free bus services for the over 60s.

Comment: @WS2 I am, here it's the same as leisure centre membership but I let my card lapse when we didn't have any online services subscriptions.  Now I can't find out we we do have until I get my new card.  It hasn't been an issue for a few years as I've been university-based and had access to all sorts of things.

Comment: @ChrisH Check with your public library. In most places all you need is a library card. Just ask if they have OED and ODNB subscriptions.

Comment: "I've dealt with Americans all my working life, and I've never heard one say sans meaning without" that's totally bizarre. 100% of Americans use "sans" to mean "without".  (and indeed as in the example, it's only used "pretentiously" - much like "sic", say).  What else would "Americans" use it to mean?

Comment: Hi @sven.  Your answer correctly points out "italicize foreign words" and gives a reference for this. However, of course, the entire issue at hand is "is a word in question foreign or not?"  Many words that were inserted for pretentious reasons and italicized in (say) the 1950s as being *francais*, are now just written and said normally.  In this case, as I mention below, the answer is: the sole and only reason to bizarrely use "sans" here, is to be pretentious, hence, go with the italics.

Comment: @JoeBlow - I like the first part of your comment, but your stubborn adherence to the notion that the "sole, only, absolutely, exactly, one (1)" reason to use _sans_ is to be pretentious seems a bit closed-minded. I prefer [this milder view](http://grammarist.com/usage/sans/).

Comment: Hmm, in the three examples given on that page, it's very much a hack journalist trying to be pretentious or funny!

Comment: Joe: I'm amazed at your ability to discern between pretentiousness and, say, deliberate brevity. Besides, I referring the overall stance, not the examples: _there is nothing wrong with using_ sans _if you like the way it sounds. Though it’s originally French, it has a long history of use in English_. They also claim it's been "widely used" for 200 years; that's an awful lot of use for every instance to be a sign of pretentious writing. And your comment supports my point; you initially alluded to "precisely one reason, absolutely, one (1) reason" – but now you've added a second (namely, humor).

Comment: Back on the Shakespeare front, I note that, in all three instances that I cited from his plays, he uses _sans_ in the context of blank verse, where a one-syllable alternative to _without_ is extremely useful. It's true that he could have had Jaques say "No teeth, nor eyes, nor taste, nor anything," but the choice of _sans_ is very effective—better in intonation and repetition and evocative sense, as Shakespeare's choices tend to be. Still, it was predominantly a verse word at that point, like _e'er_ and _e'en_, and perhaps it retains something of that uptown air today, as Joe Blow suggests.

Answer (score 17):

"Sans" is a common enough word in English that I would not bother with italics. But I also think in your sentence that the word "without" scans better, and I'd use that instead of "sans" for esthetics reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Given that "sans" [apparently](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sans) entered early enough and/or become so much part of the language that it is primarily pronounced /sænz/ and not /sɒ̃/, then it is not required that you italicise. On the other hand, if you do prefer the latter pronunciation (as I do) i.e. you are borrowing from modern French, where you're using phonemes that aren't really used except in loanwords, you probably should italicise.

"human civilization" is plainly English so should not be italicised.

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer it if you did, please, for two reasons:

- I know the word *sans* in French but not in English ... italicizing it in a sentence warns me that there's something unusual about the word. Normally when I read a sentence I scan the whole sentence, but italicizing a word is a cue for me to scan/read that word individually.
- It's normal to use 'punctuation' or *formatting* for words which have a different **emphasis** in a sentence: and because *sans* is French it has a different pronunciation, and that different pronunciation (pronunciation being like emphasis) is sufficient reason for italicising it.

Comment: As others have said, *sans* is sufficiently anglicised to be pronounced 'the plural of san' from Shakespeare onwards: it would be a solecism to pronounce it the French way.

Comment: Other *have* said that, but I don't remember having read *sans* in English (though when I look, now, I see it's in the dictionary). In [this comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222491/when-using-a-french-word-in-an-english-sentence-should-i-use-italics/222548?noredirect=1#comment473902_222491), `@WS2` suggests it's a 'foreign term' or 'odd preposition'. I'd pronounce it as English (and not italicize it) in 'sans-serif' but I wouldn't even say 'she came *sans* husband'.

Comment: Here in southern England I would have thought you'd be more likely to hear it pronounced with a vowel sound rather like the French, but (more) audible consonants at the end than in actual French.  I don't think I've ever heard *sans-serif* pronounced with /sænz/.  *Comic sans* is  better example in some ways because it doesn't pick up the /s/ from the next word. I'd expect to hear something like /sɒnz/.

Comment: The pronunciation is totally irrelevant.  Chris' answer is the correct one.  (It's worth noting that regarding "pretentious foreign words" which even the most uneducated use to appear posh ("sic" is a good example)... a funny one is "Re" (as in "in re", at the start of legal letters etc); it's funny that this is widely used "pretentiously" to "sound important" but most people thinks it's pronounced "ree", which is completely wrong of course.

Comment: Pace @Fattie, the pronunciation is relevant. It's pronounced [sænz], and that shows how assimilated it is into English. As Tim Lymington said. Sans as the OP used it is an English word (albeit derived from a French one) with an Anglicised pronunciation, so it should not be italicised. Re "re" as a preposition meaning "about, concerning": this too is an English word with an Anglicised pronunciation [ri:]. If anyone considers this pronunciation wrong, I wonder what they think are the correct pronunciations of other English borrowings from Latin, e.g. "vice versa" and "pace".