# When should Latinisms be Italicized?

Tags: latin, loanwords, typography, foreign-phrases

Some Latinisms are usually italicized in English whereas some Latin loanwords are not, even in the same text. However, I cannot find any clear pattern. Are there clear rules or guidelines about it? For example, should I italicize 'qua',  'a priori', or 'post factum'?

Comment: Consult the appropriate style guide, or choose. It's a style choice; there is no single 'rule'. There is no single right or wrong answer, although, the trend is to not italicise. Most style guides e.g. Springer, Elsevier, etc, say this. So does the Chicago Manual of Style and Scientific Style and Format. On the other hand, the Oxford Dictionary for Scientific Writers and Editors insists that _in vivo_ and _in vitro_ should be set in italics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of Italics for Latin Text](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259266/use-of-italics-for-latin-text) A rule of thumb for people unwilling to wade through the conflicting recommendations spelled out by various style guides is to italicise any obvious Latinism not found in say AHD or Collins, but not those that are. // I've found a style guide licensing say eg rather than e.g., which (the former) I find far better (note the ugly double punctuation). // I've also found one eschewing all Latin abbreviations. I ignore this one.

Comment: I rely on what I've seen before without italics. Of your example, I don't remember seeing *qua* as English, so italicized it. For 'vice versa', no. For 'a priori' and 'post factum', no.

Comment: Style manuals cannot, by themselves, resolve the OP's problem because they usually say something to the effect that the words that are perceived as foreign should be italicised, but that the words of foreign origin that are no longer so perceived should not be. It is a matter of judgement, and not of precise rules, where the boundary between the two is. Moreover, the boundary may depend on one's audience, and may shift over time.

Comment: @jsw29 - exactly. So CV for opinion-based.